# How to Add TinyMCE permanent wrapper to content area

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to add a `<div class="well">` wrapper to tinymce content body. But i dont want it gets saved with content. So it will just improve WYSIWYG because content will show in `<div class="well"></div>` when publish. This wrapper should be undeletable while using tinymce. Any idea on it?

**Update:**
here is example: 
http://unsalkorkmaz.com/twitter-embeds-in-wrong-language/

Check its comment form. Basically i moved body's background to html and made "well" class to body. Its a quick fix which i dont like much tbh. There must be some way to add a permanent root block inside editor body.

Comment: why don't you add this wrapper before submitting the content to the server? you won't be able to wrap an iframe body element into a div

Comment: This wrapper is purely cosmetic and only needs when writing content in tinymce. I thought to add to tinymce with init but then it can get deleted while editing content. Basically somehow i need tinymce need to accept `<html><body id="tinymce"><div class="well">` as root of content.

Comment: due to the fact that tinymce inserts divs or paragraphs to wrap inserted content into them your div won't wrap the whole content

Comment: an alternative would be to add the the `well` class to the tiny MCE body itself http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:body_class

Comment: ok, you don't want the wrapper div getting saved to your database. for what reason do you want to wrap the content inside this div? i am asking because there might be other options to get what you desire - just tell us what you want.

Comment: i updated question. please read update section

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have the same feature, this is how I solved it (uses Jquery for DOM manipulation):

```
$('textarea#id_body').tinymce({
    ....
    ....
    init_instance_callback : make_wysiwyg
});
```

this is how make_wysiwyg code looks like :

```
var make_wysiwyg = function(inst){
    var tmceIframe = $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentDocument || $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
    $(tmceIframe).find("body#tinymce article").wrapInner('<div class="post-content"/>');
}
```

Now, to remove this extra html that we have added, you can do a onClick event on the form submission button and before calling form.submit, call the following function:

```
var strip_wysiwyg = function() {
    var tmceIframe = $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentDocument ||     $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
    $post_content_wrapper = $(tmceIframe).find("body#tinymce div.post-content");
    $post_content = $post_content_wrapper[$post_content_wrapper.length-1];
    $($(tmceIframe).find("body#tinymce")[0]).html($($post_content).html());
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Long time passed,I remember I tried similar approach, main problem was, user can delete this format accidently. Its not permanent. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to hook into TinyMCE's save process, using the provided [save_callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asave_callback).

This will allow you to specify a function which will be called before TinyMCE completes it's save, allowing you to inject content.

A simple example, using jQuery to handle the div insertion:

```
function add_custom_div(element_id, html, body) {
        var dom = $(html);
        if ($('div.well').length < 1)
        {
            dom.wrap("<div class='wrap' /><div class='well'");
            html = dom.html();
        }
        return html;
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        save_callback : "add_custom_div"
});
```

If you need to ensure the div exists inside of TinyMCE at all times, and that the user cannot delete it, you'll want to use the [noneditable_regexp](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/noneditable_content.php) option.

Through this property, you can provide a regular expression, which, when matched by TinyMCE, will reject any attempts by the user to alter it.

Comment: This doesn't stop the user from editing or removing the outer divs though.

Comment: Added a note for that use case. Do you need sample code? I hate writing regular expressions :D

Comment: Interesting... TinyMCE seems to have a "left hand/right hand" problem.  Just this minute, I was reading the documentation for the "noneditable" plugin.  However, it looks like the demo at http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/noneditable_content.php and the documentation at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:noneditable are not the same.

Comment: This wrapper should be undeletable while using tinymce. And i dont need it while saving, i need it while using.

Comment: I looked into it. Basically i can delete all things even noneditable_regexp

Comment: Huh? No. That regex specially stops you from editing those elements, so long as you don't go into source view.